# Call python image function in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, python-imaging-library, databricks, user-defined-functions

Trying to navigate the waters between python and pyspark, I have a function for rotating images written in python:

```
from PIL import Image
def rotate_image(image, rotation_angle):
  im = Image.open(image)
  out = im.rotate(rotation_angle, expand = True)
  return out
```

I now want to use this function as a pyspark udf.

Reading in image:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn

df = spark.read.format("image").load("image2.jpg")
df.printSchema()
_udf = fn.udf(rotate_image) ##Not sure what type to declare the image as here
```

At this point, I want to apply the function to an image and declare specified angle:

```
 df.withColumn('x1', _udf(array('image', 90))).show() #Not really sure what I am doing here
```

I got an error saying

```
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 90 of type . For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

Comment: @Steven, not working. I suspect it's because the definition of the function _udf is without the datatype definition of the inputs